# Special import case in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I observed an unexcepted(imo) behaviour in python2.7. Program structure looks like this:

```
run.py
package/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
```

run.py:

```
from package import *
```

**init**.py:

```
from package.a import *
```

Consider now `a.py` and `b.py` as empty files.

In my opinion, this program should fail due circural import. Why? Because when we import `package` `init` file has an **absolute** import which indicates to access same `init` file while importing.

To see excepted by me situation just add to `a.py` this:

```
from package.b import *
```

In result we receive an ImportError.

It is a bug, or excepted behaviour? I can't find any information in docs, about special treated absolute imports in **init** files?

Comment: This has nothing to do with absolute or relative imports.

Comment: Please be more specific. For me, this is an absolut import.

Comment: @User's point is that the behavior would be the same, regardless of if you used absolute or relative importing. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried to reproduce same case, and I realized that in the day I was posting question, I was extremely tired. Question is invalid :). You guys were right that this has nothing to do with absolute imports.

`__init__.py` is loaded only once like any other module while importing and this is excepted behaviour. So in case when I have a statement like `from package.a import *` in `__init__.py` `__init__.py` is already in sys.modules (with name inherited from folder, in this case `package`) and it is not loaded again.

Circural exception will occures only when we try to use a variable from module that wasn't arleady initialized. So for example if I put in `a.py` `from package import *` interpreter will terminate with exception becouse `__init__` is not fully initialized.